# How to use Privoxy and Tor for a Scrapy project

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy, privoxy

I'm trying to scrape from http://www.apkmirror.com, but currently I'm not able to access the site anymore in my browser because its says the owner banned my IP address (see below).

[image]

I'm trying to get around this by using Privoxy and Tor, similar to what is described in http://blog.michaelyin.info/2014/02/19/scrapy-socket-proxy/.

Firstly, I installed an started [Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/), which by default listens at port 8118. I've added the following line to `/etc/privoxy/config`:

```
forward-socks5   /               127.0.0.1:9050 .
```

I also have Tor running, which is listening at port 9050 as verified using

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ netstat -tulnp | grep 9050
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

As far as I can tell using `wget`, it is working. For example, if I `wget apkmirror.com` using a proxy I get a response:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ wget www.apkmirror.com -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8118
--2017-04-24 11:02:32--  http://www.apkmirror.com/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8118... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 185097 (181K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.2’

index.html.2        100%[===================>] 180,76K  --.-KB/s    in 0,004s  

2017-04-24 11:02:44 (42,7 MB/s) - ‘index.html.2’ saved [185097/185097]
```

whereas without the proxy I get `ERROR 403: Forbidden`:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ wget www.apkmirror.com
--2017-04-24 11:01:24--  http://www.apkmirror.com/
Resolving www.apkmirror.com (www.apkmirror.com)... 104.19.134.58, 104.19.136.58, 104.19.133.58, ...
Connecting to www.apkmirror.com (www.apkmirror.com)|104.19.134.58|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-04-24 11:01:24 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Now for the Python code. I've written the following (simplified) spider:

```
import scrapy

DEBUG = True

class TorSpider(scrapy.spiders.SitemapSpider):
    name = "tor-spider"

    sitemap_urls = ['https://www.apkmirror.com/sitemap_index.xml']
    sitemap_rules = [(r'.*-android-apk-download/$', 'parse')]

    if DEBUG:
        custom_settings = {'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 20}

    def parse(self, response):
        item = {'url': response.url}
        yield item
```

I've also added the following lines to `settings.py`:

```
import os
os.environ['http_proxy'] = "http://localhost:8118"

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 1,
}
```

from what I understand from https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy, if I set the `http_proxy` environment variable the `HttpProxyMiddleware` should work. However, if I try to scrape using the command

```
scrapy crawl tor-spider -o test.json
```

I get the following response:

```
2017-04-24 10:59:17 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: proxy_spider)
2017-04-24 10:59:17 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'proxy_spider.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'test.json', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['proxy_spider.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'proxy_spider', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json'}

2017-04-24 10:59:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-04-24 10:59:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-04-24 10:59:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-04-24 10:59:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-04-24 10:59:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-04-24 10:59:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-04-24 10:59:18 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2017-04-24 10:59:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://www.apkmirror.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-04-24 10:59:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://www.apkmirror.com/sitemap_index.xml> (referer: None)
2017-04-24 10:59:18 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://www.apkmirror.com/sitemap_index.xml>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2017-04-24 10:59:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-04-24 10:59:18 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 519,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 3110,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 24, 8, 59, 18, 927878),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 24, 8, 59, 18, 489419)}
2017-04-24 10:59:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

In short, I'm still getting the `403` error with the scraper despite trying to scrape anonymously using Privoxy/Tor. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

akpmirror is using cloudflare to protect themselves (among other things) against scraping and bots.

Most probably they have scrapy's standard user agent blacklisted. So in addition to using a tor IP (which btw can also be easily blacklisted) you should also set a user agent header that looks like a real browser:

in settings.py

```
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"
```

(see https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent for details)